# What is the sequence of write operations I can use to store n objects of variable length (l) with the least number of writes of length m (l<=m)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, computer-science, knapsack-problem

I have a set of n=4 objects, each with a variable length (l). I also have a mechanism to store m bytes at a time (m > n and m >= l). How would I be able to efficiently store all n=4 objects with the least number of writes.

Comment: Since `m >= l`, just make one write per object? It's a bit unclear what the constraints are.

Comment: But that would be n=4 writes. You can pack more objects in one write operation to limit the number of writes. The lenght of the objects can be greater or less than m, but each object's length can be different than other objects.

Comment: With `n=4`, there are only 14 possible combinations, so just calculate them all and pick the smallest one.

Comment: @edwardbasil The length of the objects cannot be greater than m, as you specified `m >= l`.

Comment: @edwardbasil "*You can pack more objects in one write operation*" - how? And can pack one half of an object in one write and the other half in the next? Since you're apparently writing bytes, can you choose at which index you write?